# Financial SEC Filling Table data Extraction Using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to build a ML system which extracts financial data from Tables.

Sample table is like below.

[image]

From the above image you can see **Net sales** is an attribute along with two values 2707.1 and 1994.5 for 2 different  quarters. So I want to extract those data with meta data like The date, Quarter,  Currency value etc.,. Like below image.
[image]

Normally if it is in Free Text I use Entity extraction methods using Spacy or other modules.
We can not apply rules because there will be many variety of table from which we have to extract from.

**Edit:**
The data are from HTML file.

A [sample website](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/23217/000119312519081456/d721787dex991.htm)

Comment: If tables are from 10K/10Q types of statements,  ML might not be required since tools can already extract these kind of tables (E.g: https://tabula.technology/)

Comment: It depends on how the data is stored (e.g., pdf, html, plain text, LaTeX, MS Word, Pages, ...). Please be more specific.

Comment: @BrianSpiering apologies for the inconvenience caused I have added the source for reference

Comment: @ShamitVerma Thanks I will look at it and let you know. My requirement it not just about extracting table. I also want to map the attributes so that I can extract attributes with meaning from them. I.e.) Net Sales: 2707.1 for weeks third weeks ended quarter third quarter and date February etc.,.

Comment: The screen scraping exercise is pretty trivial.  I'm curious to know how ML plays a part in income statement analysis.  What does Net Sales: 2707.1 tell you?  What kind of improved intelligence or learning enhancement do you get from that data point?  Will you look at changes over time (time-series analysis)?  What is the end game here?  Thanks.